# CAGradientLayer not applying to the full view in programmatically created UI

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, bounds, cagradientlayer

I'm working on an iOS project that's creating all its UIs programmatically. Not storyboards.

I want to add a gradient to the background of a UIViewController's UIView.

I created the following extension method.

```
extension UIView {
    
    func addGradient(colors: [UIColor]) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.bounds = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
    
}
```

And I added the gradient in the `viewDidLoad` of the ViewController like so.

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: 0.28, green: 0.521, blue: 0.696, alpha: 1)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0.575, green: 0.615, blue: 0.692, alpha: 1)
view.addGradient(colors: [topColor, bottomColor])
```

But the gradient is not being applied to the full width and height of the screen.

[image]

I printed out the bounds of the view and it shows these values.

> (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)

So I'm not sure why the gradient is still not covering the full view.

Comment: in View Did layout subview update frame of the gradient, should not set bounds,use frame instead

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I tried that too. Still doesn't change anything.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Comment: @matt I moved the gradient setting code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it still doesn't work for some reason. [Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/847v7skpkccjd8x/gradientdemo.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addGradient(colors:)` method set the `gradientLayer's` `frame` instead of `bounds`, i.e.

```
func addGradient(colors: [UIColor]) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds //here.....

    //rest of the code...
}
```

Also, as suggested move your code to **`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`** method,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 0.28, green: 0.521, blue: 0.696, alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0.575, green: 0.615, blue: 0.692, alpha: 1)
    view.addGradient(colors: [topColor, bottomColor])
}
```

This is because, the `gradient's` `frame` must change everytime there are any changes in the `view's` layout. Example, in portrait and landscape orientations.

Answer (score 1):

When we are adding view bounds to Gradient layer frame that time we have to update frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews. It works fine for me
Following worked for me

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    self.gradient.frame = containerView.bounds
}
```

containerView is the view where i am setting gradient layer.